# Assign a json object to request.json in flask

Tags: python, json, flask

Usually request.json is used to access json objects send to a flask view. I would like to assign something to request.json

```
from flask import request
print("request.json = ", request.json)
print("request.form['json'] = ", request.form['json'])
request.json = jsonify(request.form['json'])
```

leads to

```
request.json =  None
request.form['json'] =  {
    "test": "test"
}
Traceback (most recent call last):
 ...
  File "/ajax_handlers.py", line 952, in X
    request.json = jsonify(request.form['json'])
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 365, in <lambda>
    __setattr__ = lambda x, n, v: setattr(x._get_current_object(), n, v)
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Any idea how I can assign a json object to request.json?

Comment: Why do you want to change the request?

Comment: just to make sure the request object always has the content expected in the code later on... this would be the easiest change of the existing code

Comment: This issue happens because you can't set `request.json`. So, instead use `x = jsonify(request.form['json'])` and `x` will be the response

Comment: but x will not have the same properties... for example x.get('') will not work...

Answer (score 1):

Presumably for safety, you cannot replace the values on a request object; they come in from the client, and they remain as-is. When you think about it, that's good practice; if various pieces of code try to modify your request object's data in various ways, it would lead to inconsistent and hard-to-test code.

As an alternative, you can assign meaningful attributes that aren't part of the default request object. For example, perhaps you're trying to remember, for elsewhere in your stack, who the user is authenticated as:

```py
# Don't do this!
flask.request.json['authenticated_user'] = authenticated_user
```

That's messing with the original request data; don't do that. It'll make debugging (not to mention security) a nightmare. A better alternative:

```py
# Do this instead
flask.request.authenticated_user = authenticated_user
```

You can *add to* the existing request with new attributes, but you can't go replacing existing properties on the request. Nor should you try!